# Method .replace in python

Tags: python, pandas

Could some one explain to me why use this code:

```
df[["normalized-losses"]].replace(np.nan, avg_norm_loss, inplace=True)
```

Give-me this error: "/home/jupyterlab/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4389: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

While this code works perfectly

```
df["normalized-losses"].replace(np.nan, avg_norm_loss, inplace=True)
```

I have a theory that's because the method replace have to use paramaters with these types: str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None, so when I tried to use the first code I have a dataframe type, am I right or wrong?

Comment: The latter operates directly on the column. The former acts on a new copy of a dataframe created with one column.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the following `df[['column']]`, pandas creates a new object in memory. If you assign a variable using `new_df = df[['column']]`, then the object is not destroyed. However, when you apply an 'inplace' method to a copy in memory, pandas creates this object for nothing as it will be destroyed. Thus the `SettingWithCopyWarning` flag was created to warn users that they are performing a useless operation.

In contrast, using `df['column']`, this returns an actual Series that is present in the DataFrame and that can be modified in place.

Comment: Tks mozway for your help!